# Double name input field when using PaymentElement and AddressElement with stripe.js

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm setting up a stripe payment method with elements. Everything works as expected, there is only one small styling issue that I can't resolve. The name input field shows up twice, in the address element of course,  and also when the 'automatic_payment_methods' in the backend paymentIntent is set to 'enabled:true'. So this happens when there are multiple payment options, not only for creditcard. Is it possible to remove that extra name field that shows, when for example you select iDeal or is it built-in?

[image: Stripe checkout]

Checkout form

```
<form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <AddressElement options={{mode: 'billing'}}/>
            <PaymentElement />
     <button disabled={isProcessing} id="submit">
         <span id="button-text">
             {isProcessing ? "Processing..." : "Pay now"}
         </span>
     </button>
     {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
```

Payment

```
<Elements key={clientSecret} stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret, appearance }}>
       <CheckoutForm />
</Elements>
```

Api

```
app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
let amount = 995
try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        currency: "eur",
        amount: amount,
        automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
    });

    // Send publishable key and PaymentIntent details to client
    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        paymentIntent: paymentIntent
    });
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send({
        error: {
            message: e.message,
        },
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to disable billing name collection in Payment Element. You could set [`fields.billingDetails.name`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-fields-billingDetails-name) to `never` when creating Payment Element.

For example,

```
// Set options for Payment Element
const options = {
  fields: {
    billingDetails: {
      name: 'never',
    },
  },
};

// Create Payment Element
<PaymentElement options={options}/>
```